# can not create project using scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

cannot create a project use scrapy

```
...

(crawler-env) D:\_pyproject\scrapy-project>scrapy startproject xxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\_111\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\_111\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\crawler-env\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\administrator\envs\crawler-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "c:\users\administrator\envs\crawler-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\users\administrator\envs\crawler-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "c:\users\administrator\envs\crawler-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\startproject.py", line 109, in run
    ProjectName=string_camelcase(project_name))
  File "c:\users\administrator\envs\crawler-env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\template.py", line 9, in render_templatefile
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xxx\\xxx\\settings.py.tmpl'

(crawler-env) D:\_pyproject\scrapy-project>
```

Comment: `No such file or directory: 'xxx\\xxx\\settings.py.tmpl'` the file seems to be required and does not exists

Comment: maybe this file should be created t automaticlly when using this command to create project, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you follow [official scrapy installation guide](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)?

Comment: It was installed before, then today this error occurred. I finally fixed it by reinstalling it.